# Directive cannot access scope data source

Tags: angularjs

I have simple directive like this

View:

```
<div ng-if="newReg.checkedDomains.length>0">    
   <div extension-list="newReg.checkedDomains"></div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('starweb')
.directive('extensionList', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var data = scope[attrs['extensionList']];
            console.log(data);  
        },

        template:"<div>test</div>"
    }
});
```

console log always shows Undefined ? Why directive cannot access the extensionList source data ?

Comment: scope[attrs['extensionList']] translates to scope['newReg.checkedDomains'] which is not defined. It should be scope.newReg.checkedDomains or scope[newReg][checkedDomains]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extensionList` attribute holds a binding expression, property chain with a dot, which cannot be directly accessed with bracket notation on the object. So you would just need to `eval` it on the scope. Had it been just a property directly on the scope, bracket notation that you are trying to do on the scope would have worked, but in your actual case you are one more level down (provided name of the attribute and the property name on the scope are the same).

Try:-

```
 var data = scope.$eval(attrs.extensionList);
 console.log(data);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/p7xjNN?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for your help. it seems to work properly but somehow in my case it always return the first object, maybe i did wrong somewhere. I'll figure it out. thnx again